# test 404 and 500 pages on rails develpment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to write my 404 and 500 pages for my Rails 3.2.16 application. I've added to the `application_controller.rb` the following:

```
  def local_request?
    false
  end

  binding.pry
  unless  ActionController::Base.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception, with: :render_500
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
  end

  def render_404(exception)
    logger.warning exception.backtrace.join("\n")
    @not_found_path = exception.message
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end

  def render_500(exception)
    logger.error exception.backtrace.join("\n")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/internal_server_error', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 500 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 500}
    end
  end
```

Though when I set my browser on `http://localhost:3000/nonexistent`, I see in the logs:

```
Started GET "/nonexistent" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-22 13:45:12 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/nonexistent"):
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (3.2ms)
```

It seems that the application_controller is not even executed so it doesn't load my custom 404 page.

I'm not sure how to solve this, and how to visualize the 404 and 500 pages on my development environment to make sure they look the way I want.

thanks,

Comment: I've got a better way for you - let me write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better way to do this:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
-> config/application.rb if you want on all environments
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }


#app/controllers/exception_controller.rb
class ExceptionController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

    #Dependencies
    before_action :status

  #Layout
  layout :layout_status

  ####################
  #      Action      #
  ####################

    #Show
  def show
    respond_with status: @status
  end

  ####################
  #   Dependencies   #
  ####################

  protected

  #Info
  def status
    @exception  = env['action_dispatch.exception']
    @status     = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
    @response   = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses[@exception.class.name]
  end

  #Format
  def details
    @details ||= {}.tap do |h|
      I18n.with_options scope: [:exception, :show, @response], exception_name: @exception.class.name, exception_message: @exception.message do |i18n|
        h[:name]    = i18n.t "#{@exception.class.name.underscore}.title", default: i18n.t(:title, default: @exception.class.name)
        h[:message] = i18n.t "#{@exception.class.name.underscore}.description", default: i18n.t(:description, default: @exception.message)
      end
    end
  end
  helper_method :details

  ####################
  #      Layout      #
  ####################

  private

  #Layout
  def layout_status
    @status.to_s == "404" ? "application" : "error"
  end

end

#app/views/exception/show.html.haml
.box
%h1
    = details[:name]
%p
    = details[:message]
```

This works. Use `@interpidd`'s answer if you want to run in dev

Comment: thank you for the nice response, I've tried it, added: 
`config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }` to `/config/application.rb` and created the class with everything. still when I go to the non existent page in `development` env I see the default routing error page: `No route matches [GET] "/nonexistent"
`

Comment: Have you gone into `config/environments/development.rb` and set `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` ?

Comment: ah... good point, I thought this wasn't necessary with your solution, it doesn't work still though, now when I get to the non existent page I get a 500 error page.

Comment: hmmm okay! Would you mind going to the chat about this?

Comment: The chat? what do you mean?

Comment: Stackoverflow Chatroom for RoR!

Comment: let me find it, I didn't know there was one 0_0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51202/discussion-between-don-giulio-and-rich-peck)

Comment: Ok, we figured that the script was written for Rails 4, while I'm on Raisl 3.2.16, `before_action` has been introduced only in the new version, in the old one I need to change to `before_filter`, then it works

Answer (score 3):

In development.rb

Change

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

to

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

And restart your server. Your error pages will be displayed without all the debugging.

Comment: Thanks, but still my application_controller isn't executed, (ie. the binding.pry is not ran).

Comment: That's because rails does not have to go through ActionController when an route is not found :)

Comment: You can test your custom 404 and 500 page by going in an action that calls render_404 or render_500.

When rails does not find a route, it will look in public/404.html, but you can change this behavior (look up rails exception app)

Answer (score 2):

Better you start the server in production mode and verify it.

```
rails s -eproduction
```

then it will render the error page.

Comment: Nice idea, though with this I have to have a `production.rb` environment file that's in reality a `develompent` configuration file.