# Testing Rails 404 and 500 JSON reponse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-6

I am building a JSON backend API with Rails, and I can't seem to figure this out: How can one test using RSpec the Rails default error responses? For example, for a generic 404 request, I currently have the following request spec:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe '404 errors' do
  let(:json) { JSON.parse(response.body) }

  before { get '/noexistent', headers: headers }

  # examples
end
```

Rails, however, refuses to render the 404 response that it would normally yield, instead simply raising:

> ActionController::RoutingError:
>   No route matches [GET] "/404"

I've tried removing `config.consider_all_request_local = true` from `config/environments/test.rb`, with no results.

Note that I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220110/test-404-and-500-pages-on-rails-develpment) (it's where I got the idea for `consider_all_requests_local`), but it applies to development, not testing.

---

**EDIT:** I am using `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` to redirect errors to an `ErrorsController`. This works fine in development or production, but not while testing. When testing, I still get the above error. Any ideas?

Comment: Basically, if you want to render json instead of RoutingError, you need to "intercept" those routes in routes.rb. For example, you'll redirect unexisting requests to controller Errors#not_found. And inside of it you might render whatever you need like render json: { errors: "Not found" }, status: 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer was rather simple. I had to change this line in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```rb
  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
```

to:

```rb
  # Do not raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```